# QStyleSheet over-riding general style

Tags: css, qt, qt5

I'm trying to change the color of QComboBox (or a few widgets actually) but it seems that when I create a QStyleSheet with just a color property, it over writes all the other properties.  Most notably on Windows, rounded QComboBoxes become square, and rather ugly.  Snippet below (note that the colors in the actual code are generated.  Just using black on white for ease).

```
QString styleSheet = "QComboBox { background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000 }";
combBox->setStyleSheet( styleSheet );
```

Sorry for the ridiculous sizing of these images.

This is a regular, non-styled QComboBox:

[image]

And this is a QComboBox after applying the aforementioned style:

[image]

Comment: It would appear you are setting the new stylesheet as the *only* stylesheet to be applied. That would indeed remove all the other styles. Instead, try adding the new style to the existing stylesheet instead, or if you can't do that, try to add it as an additional stylesheet rather than replacing the old one.

Comment: How do I add instead of replace?  The docs basically say setStyleSheet is all I have.

Comment: I had a look at the [QT documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-a-qpushbutton-using-the-box-model) which outlines this issue for a button, but the principle is the same. If you modify a property that cannot be resolved through native styles (like you're doing here), you need to style the entire element, because all native styles are ignored for the element.

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda brutal - I just want to change the one element. :|  Guess I can deal w/ the palette directly.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Dynamic Stylesheets.

Reference: https://wiki.qt.io/Dynamic_Properties_and_Stylesheets

try using this in your code:

```
ui->comboBox->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(16, 72, 255); color: rgb(255, 17, 80);");
```

It's like append your stylesheet to the widget stylesheet.

Comment: He is not using dynamic property. Your stylesheet is not safe. It has no scope, may affect to children of that combobox

Comment: Can you offer the safe version?   Right now, I can't think of this combo box having children, but it's pretty generic.  Definitely could happen in the future.

Comment: And even after applying it, it still gives the same ugly look.

Comment: Believe me it is a safe, programmers always using this method, in the future if you made children for that comboBox just override the method.

Comment: This actually did not solve my issue -- safe or not, it still strips the widget of other characteristics, unfortunately.